# How can I get return value within while statement written in python?

Tags: python, while-loop, return-value

I have a function to determine the UpdateStatus:

```
def detemUpStatus(localTuple, newTuple):
    # some logic...
    # it would return integer which would get processed later
    return int(some number predefined)
```

The `detemUpStatus` would return 0 if we didn't needs update, so I decided to put this in the `while` statement like:

```
while (returnValue = detemUpStatus(lT, nT)):
    # some logic to do process update
    #   with returnValue...
```

which returns

> ```
> while (i = 2):
>         ^
> ```
>
> SyntaxError: invalid syntax

I am pretty new to python, I think there should be an elegant way like `C` the language does.

Comment: `=` is assignment. `==` is comparison

Comment: `==` is comparison operator to check equals. `=` is assignment operator

Comment: Hi Adam, haifzhan: I would like to assignment the return value of `detemUpStatus` to something not globaly view-able, so I can use it with in `while loop` and `detemUpStatus` would return *4* kinds of integer in this example. Thanks.

Comment: Python doesn't let you use an assignment as a value (or a condition). You could change your loop condition to `True`, get the value in the next line, and `break` if it is false.

Comment: @khelwood Thank you very much!

Comment: this makes no sense ... why not just put "return 0" at the end of the while loop ...

Comment: @JoranBeasley I would update some global dirty bits within `while` loop which would resort in `detemUpStatus` returns a different value. So I can focus in update logic within `while` loop body, let `detemUpStatus` do the *pure* justify stuff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you're going to be able to do the assignment in the `while` clause. Some alternatives:

```
returnValue = detemUpStatus(lT, nT)
while returnValue:
    ...
    returnValue = detemUpStatus(lT, nT)
```

or maybe:

```
while True:
    returnValue = detemUpStatus(lT, nT)
    if not returnValue:
        break
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do assignment in the while like C does but you can use a for loop using `iter` with a sentinel value to loop until the function returns `0` allowing you to use the status returned in the loop:

```
for status in  iter(lambda: detemUpStatus(arg1,arg2), 0):
    # use status
```